# How to install PySide2 in a Python3 virtual environment on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.5, raspberry-pi3, pyside2

I am having a hard time installing PySide2 in a Python3 virtual enviroment on a Raspberry Pi3. I use *Python-3.5.3* and the updated version of *pip*.

```
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which cmake
/usr/bin/cmake
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which python
/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/python
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python --version
Python 3.5.3
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip --version
pip 19.0.1 from /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 --version
pip 19.0.1 from /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

First I tried to install with pip install PySide2 but I got the error

```
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install PySide2
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting PySide2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PySide2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PySide2
```

Following the instructions found at https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/GettingStarted on how to install via the official release wheels of Qt for Python also gives an error.

```
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install --index-url=https://download.qt.io/official_releases/QtForPython/ pyside2 --trusted-host download.qt.io
Looking in indexes: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/QtForPython/, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pyside2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyside2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyside2
```

Then I followed the instructions on the official package site https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/. I installed the dependencies, including *libclang* and build from source as suggested without any errors.

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/pyside/pyside-setup
cd pyside-setup
git branch --track 5.12 origin/5.12
git checkout 5.12
python setup.py install --qmake=</usr/bin/qmake/> --parallel=8 --build-tests
```

Yet after all this work, there are no signs of the module PySide2

```
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~/pyside-setup $ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PySide2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PySide2'
>>>
```

Next thing I followed the instructions found on https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python/GettingStarted/X11. I clone the official repository, checked the versions are fine and then build using the *qmake* path /opt/Qt5.12/bin/qmake:

```
(cv3) pi@raspberrypi:~/pyside-setup $ python setup.py build --qmake=/opt/Qt5.12/bin/qmake --parallel=4 --build-tests --ignore-git
```

and the build gave two errors:
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:95 (message):
    Unable to detect CLANG location by checking LLVM_INSTALL_DIR, CLANG_INSTALL_DIR or running llvm-config.

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/pyside-setup/cv33_build/py3.5-qt5.12.0-32bit-release/shiboken2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
error: Error configuring shiboken2
```

I guessed perhaps updating *CLANG* and *CMAKE* will make a change. So I did the update to the latest version and the process went well without errors. Then I

While building PySide2 the process exits at 47% with the following error:

```
[ 47%] Linking CXX executable shiboken2
/home/pi/libclang/lib/libclang.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
generator/CMakeFiles/shiboken2.dir/build.make:181: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "generator/shiboken2" non riuscito
make[2]: *** [generator/shiboken2] Errore 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2877: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "generator/CMakeFiles/shiboken2.dir/all" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [generator/CMakeFiles/shiboken2.dir/all] Errore 2
Makefile:140: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all" non riuscito
make: *** [all] Errore 2
error: Error compiling shiboken2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 296, in <module>
setup_runner.run_setup()
File "/home/pi/pyside-setup/build_scripts/setup_runner.py", line 157, in run_setup
raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: 
setup.py invocation failed with exit code: 1.


setup.py invocation was: /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/python setup.py build --qmake=/opt/Qt5.12/bin/qmake --parallel=4 --build-tests --ignore-git --internal-build-type=shiboken2
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: No change after installing LLVM and exporting it to the PySide2 build folder `export LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=$PWD/libclang`

Comment: No change also after installing CLANG the traditional way with `sudo apt-get install clang`. The installed version was 3.8.x.

Answer (score 0):

As the version of the installed `CLANG` was out of date, I tried with updating it first by following the instructions found on [codepool.biz](https://www.codepool.biz/installing-llvm-windows-raspbian-macos.html). No problems arised.

Then again I pointed the `LLVM` and `CLANG` libraries to the PySide2 installation path with

```
export CLANG_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/clang_7.0.
export LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/local/clang_7.0.0
```

The build process successfully passed the 47% percent treeshold and finished bulding `shiboken2` but got stuck at the `PySide2` step at 2%. The error:

```
[  2%] Built target pyside2
Makefile:140: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "all" non riuscito
make: *** [all] Errore 2
error: Error compiling pyside2
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 296, in <module>
      setup_runner.run_setup()
   File "/home/pi/pyside-setup/build_scripts/setup_runner.py", line 157, in run_setup
      raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: 
setup.py invocation failed with exit code: 1.

setup.py invocation was: /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/python setup.py build --qmake=/opt/Qt5.12/bin/qmake --parallel=4 --build-tests --ignore-git --internal-build-type=pyside2
```

What is going on?